# Stop CTRL-Click from affecting parent datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that has another datagrid declared within the RowDetailsTemplate;

```
<DataGrid name="dataGrid1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
  ...
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DataGrid name="dataGrid2">
        ...
      </DataGrid/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

When I CTRL-Click a row on the child DataGrid, it un-selects the parent datagrid's `SelectedItem` and hides the `RowDetailsTemplate`.

I assume this is some kind of Routed Event behaviour, but I've tried to catch `MouseDown`/`LeftButtonMouseDown` on the datagrid but no event is fired.  I've also caught the `SelectedItemChanged` event on the child datagrid and set `e.Handled = true;` but the event still triggers on the parent.

How can I stop the parent datagrid from unselecting when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Clicking a child DataGridRow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catching `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` at the child control, setting `e.Handled = true` and `dataGridRow.IsSelected = !dataGridRow.IsSelected` fixed this.