# How to disable unselection in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a ***datagrid*** with **SelectionMode** = "single" , but when i press 'ctrl' and select the ***selected*** row , it became ***unselected***. There is a way to disable the 'ctrl' command or make it that when is pressed it doesn't ***unselect*** the selected row?

I am using **WPF** and **MVVM** Pattern.

I tried with

> PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"

and handled it like this but doesn't worked :

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

 e.handled = true;

    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The [answer on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388655/stop-ctrl-click-from-affecting-parent-datagrid) suggests that there's more than just setting `Handled` to true. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502150/wpf-datagrid-get-row-number-which-mouse-cursor-is-on) might be helpful.

Both combined the result could look like this:

```
void DataGridPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    var result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(gd, e.GetPosition(gd));
    var row = DependencyObjectHelper.FindAncestor<DataGridRow>(result.VisualHit);
    if (row != null && !row.IsSelected)
        row.IsSelected = true;
}
```

I suggest you take a closer look into existing questions & answers and combine these to accomplish what you want to do.